# recaptcha not showing on centos server

Tags: linux, centos, recaptcha, iptables

I use recaptcha for one of my pages. When deployed locally everything is working fine, but when deployed to the CentOS server the image is not rendered. I have the following in my application:

```
$.getScript('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js',
                          function showRecaptcha() {         
                                Recaptcha.create("my_public_key",
                                    "recaptcha_div",
                                    {
                                      theme: "clean",
                                      callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
                                    }
                                );
                  });
```

I edited/restarted my iptables to accept output on port 80 :

```
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2077 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

and still nothing. I even run the application on Tomcat as a root, and same result... Any ideas?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So there was no technical problem, just that the recaptcha key I used was for a different domain...